# The Quest for a Bicubic Planar Dessin D'Enfants

Tags: graph-theory, riemann-surfaces

The basic building block in any cubic bipartite graph is the following:

$\hskip1.7in$[image]

This fragment is taken from the french wiki page on [Dessin D'Enfants](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dessin_d%27enfant_(math%C3%A9matiques)#Topologie) (for a english translation go [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2707896/19341)), but, up to now, I've never seen a full-blown example of a bicubic graph, that qualifies as a [dessin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dessin_d%27enfant).
By the latter, I mean, given such a graph, what is the corresponding $p(x)$?

Can anyone point towards a (simple) worked-out example?

**UPDATE** Looks like I found something

$\hskip1.7in$[image]

Unfortunately the paper ["Bipartite graph embeddings, Riemann surfaces and Galois groups"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X15000977) by Gareth A. Jones is not freely available...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found something in

["The field of moduli and fields of definition of
dessins d’enfants"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.7736.pdf) by Moises Herradon Cueto

> As an example, we can take the cube dessin on the sphere

$\hskip1.7in$[image]

> ... This holomorphic map is given by the equation
>   $$ f(z)=-\frac{1}{12\sqrt 3} \frac{(z^4-2\sqrt 3 z^2 -1)^3}{z^2(z^4+1)^2}$$